# FadeOut a div with svg

Tags: jquery

I have a div and I can fadeOut it with jQuery. But when I put a svg inside that div, I cannot do that anymore. Is it possible to fadeOut a div with a svg inside?

HTML:

```
<div id="interrogant">
<object data="interrogant.svg" width="80" height="150" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#interrogant{cursor: pointer; background-color:blue; width:80px; height:150px;}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){   
    $("#interrogant").click(function() {
        $("#interrogant").fadeOut("normal");
    });     
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that when I put a svg in a div I cannot fadeOut or do anything with jQuery with it. But I can If I create another div outside or even on top of that div.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(function(){   
    $("div#interrogant object").click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut("normal");
    });     
});
```

unless you need to use the data attribute

```
$('object[data="interrogant.svg"]').click(function() {
```

Comment: I try it here and it did not work: http://jsfiddle.net/f8pze/  I don't understand why do you think it should work? what is different from my example?